# Cucumber and Eclipse IDE; How to make jar for a test case

Tags: eclipse, maven, cucumber

I'm a Cucumber and Eclipse beginner and have a few questions and hope you can help me to get through this:  I created a sample cucumber test scenario, a sample test steps and a cucumber runner. The scenarios runs fine within eclipse IDE (Neon).  I used Maven as the dependency manager.  I also installed the Maven command line module.  The step code is Java.
  Here is the (basic) question:  How do I create a jar file from my cucumber test scenario so that execute it via command line so that I can bring the test scenario to Jenkins CI?  Is there anything I need to do with Maven BEFORE I can build the jar file?
  Thanks a lot folks!

Answer (score 0):

If you run Cucumber using the JUnit runner, then all you have to do to run from a command line is to execute Maven and make sure you invoke a life cycle phase that includes running the unit tests. One way would be

```
mvn test
```

An example that might get you up and running can be found at 
https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber-java-skeleton

Comment: Hi Thomas,  Thanks a lot for the link but I'm not sure of the command "man test does.  I can see it run some kind of cucumber scenarios ( I did not look into the files et to find out what the test scenario looks like).  Now my question is:  does  that command "man test' produces some kind of jar file for a test case?  If so, then where is the jar file is saved?  another question:  If I have multiple test scenarioes

Comment: Hi Thomas,  Thanks a lot for the link but I'm not sure of the command "man test does.  I can see it run some kind of cucumber scenarios ( I did not look into the files et to find out what the test scenario looks like).  Now my question is:  does  that command "man test' produces some kind of jar file for a test case?  If so, then where is the jar file is saved?  Another question:  If I have multiple test scenarios and I run that "man test" command, does it create a bunch of jar files for each of the test scenario?

Comment: The command mvn test will execute Maven and that will in turn run the tests. There is one test that will run Cucumber, it is called RunCukesTest. The net result is that you will execute Cucumber using Maven.

Comment: Thomas.  I'm getting better to understand Maven... but still there are a lot more to learn.  I got the command "man test" works and now I understand it .  You mentioned the "RunCukeTest".  Is it the "master" test runner where you specify the dirs for all the test step files and feature files?  If that is what I understand, then when maven builds the jar ( "man build"), then it would lump every thing all together in one single jar?  In other words, all test scenarios and their test steps would be complied into one single jar?  Then the command "man test" would execute all of scenarios? Thanks

Comment: Maven will build a jar with your production code. During that process, it will execute the tests if they are defined in the test part of the project (src/test/java/...) The test code will not be included in the resulting jar, the test code is only there for verifying that you didn't break anything by accident when you implemented your production code.